# Not able to run Python functions with Airflow

Tags: python, docker, function, airflow

I'm fairly new to Airflow and trying to understand the basics. Right now I was making a task flow where I would have multiple tasks that pass information to each other. The idea is that task 1 scrapes the top 10 songs in the charts of the week. Task 2 puts this information in a CSV file. Task 2a sends this CSV file to my mail if succesful, task 2b sends me an email that it failed if unsuccesful.

Now the issue that I'm having is that I can't run these functions inside of my DAG configuration file. I get errors like '*airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: `python_callable` param must be callable*'. I have uploaded my code to this GitRepo: https://github.com/larsje99/airflow_problem

Hopefully someone can help identify my problem on what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Airflow through Docker, so my docker compose file is also present in the repo!

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

Cheers!

Comment: You can just put your code in the post...

Comment: Can we see the full stack trace of your errors?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy After removing the `()` from the `python_callable` param. I get this error in my Airflow UI:

`Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/weekly_top10_charts.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/weekly_top10_charts.py", line 15, in <module>
    from scripts.make_csv import MakeCSVFile
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/scripts/make_csv.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scrape_script import ScrapeTop10List
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrape_script'`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `()` from the `python_callable` param.

It's going to get called in the `PythonOperator` so it's expecting just the function and not the function called.

example:

```
        task_2 = PythonOperator(
                task_id='make_csv',
                python_callable=MakeCSVFile)
```

Comment: This worked! Still had to change something in my path definition when mailing the csv to me! But it works now, thanks for the help guys!